# Can I show Articles in a tree like structure

Tags: knowledge

We would like to show Knowledge Articles in a tree like structure, has anyone done this? I am looking for sample code & steps to accomplish.

Thank You,

Comment: Check this article   https://iwritecrappycode.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/lets-build-a-tree-from-salesforce-com-data-categories/

Answer (score 0):

From this [blog](https://iwritecrappycode.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/lets-build-a-tree-from-salesforce-com-data-categories/)

First off, lets grab the static resource and get that uploaded into your org. You can snag it here

https://www.box.com/s/04u0cd8xjtm0z84tbhid

upload that, make it public, call it jsTree

```
global class CaseSlaController
{
    //constructors for component and visualforce page extension
    public CaseSlaController() {}
    public CaseSlaController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {}

    //gets category data and returns in JSON format for visualforce pages. Beware that since we end up double JSON encoding the return 
    //(once from the JSON.serialize, and another time because that's how data is returned when moved over apex remoting) you have to fix
    //the data on the client side. We have to double encode it because the built in JSON encoder breaks down when trying to serialize
    //the Schema.DescribeDataCategoryGroupStructureResult object, but the explicit call works.
    @remoteAction 
    global static string getCategoriesJson(string sObjectType)
    {
        return JSON.serialize(CaseSlaController.getCategories(sObjectType));
    }

    public static  list<Schema.DescribeDataCategoryGroupStructureResult> getCategories(string sObjectType)
    {

        //the describing of categories requires pairs of sObject type, and category name. This holds a list of those pairs.
        list<Schema.DataCategoryGroupSObjectTypePair> pairs = new list<Schema.DataCategoryGroupSObjectTypePair>();

        //list of objects to describe, for this app we only take 1 sObject type at a time, as passed into this function.
        list<string> objects = new list<string>();
        objects.add(sObjectType);

        //describe the categories for this object type (knowledgeArticleVersion)
        List<Schema.DescribeDataCategoryGroupResult> describeCategoryResult =  Schema.describeDataCategoryGroups(objects);

        //add the found categories to the list.
        for(Schema.DescribeDataCategoryGroupResult s : describeCategoryResult)
        {
            Schema.DataCategoryGroupSObjectTypePair thisPair = new Schema.DataCategoryGroupSObjectTypePair();
            thisPair.sObject = sObjectType;
            thisPair.dataCategoryGroupName = s.getName();
            pairs.add(thisPair);            
        }

        //describe the categories recursivly
        list<Schema.DescribeDataCategoryGroupStructureResult> results = Schema.describeDataCategoryGroupStructures(pairs,false);

        return results;
    }    
    private static DataCategory[] getAllCategories(DataCategory [] categories)
    {
        if(categories.isEmpty())
        {
            return new DataCategory[]{};
        } 
        else
        {
            DataCategory [] categoriesClone = categories.clone();
            DataCategory category = categoriesClone[0];
            DataCategory[] allCategories = new DataCategory[]{category};
            categoriesClone.remove(0);
            categoriesClone.addAll(category.getChildCategories());
            allCategories.addAll(getAllCategories(categoriesClone));
            return allCategories;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
    <apex:component Controller="CaseSlaController">
    <!---- Two parameters can be passed into this component ---->
    <apex:attribute name="sObjectType" type="string" description="the sObject type to get data category tree for" />
    <apex:attribute name="callback" type="string" description="Name of javascript function to call when tree drawing is complete" />

    <!--- include the required libraries --->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{!URLFOR($Resource.jsTree, 'css/jquery.treeview.css')}" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jsTree, 'js/jquery.min.js')}" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jsTree, 'js/jquery.treeview.js')}" />

    <script>
        //put jQuery in no conflict mode
        j$=jQuery.noConflict();     

        //object to hold all our functions and variables, keep things organized and dont pollute the heap
        var categorySelect = new Object();

        //invokes the getCategoriesJson function on the apex controller. Returns to the callback function with the
        //fetched data
        categorySelect.getCategoryData = function(sObjectType,callback)
        {
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                '{!$RemoteAction.CaseSlaController.getCategoriesJson}', 
                sObjectType,
                function(result, event){
                   callback(result,event);
                }, 
                {escape: true}
            );          
        }    

        //as soon as the dom has loaded lets get to work
        j$(document).ready(function() {

            //first off, find all the data category data for the given sObject type.       
            categorySelect.getCategoryData('{!sObjectType}',function(result,event)
            {
                //the json data we get back is all screwed up. Since it got JSON encoded twice quotes become the html
                //&quote; and such. So we fix the JSON and reparse it. I know its kind of hacky but I dont know of a better way

                var fixedJson = JSON.parse(categorySelect.htmlDecode(result));         

                //lets create the series of nested lists required for our tree plugin from the json data.
                var html = categorySelect.buildTreeHtml(fixedJson);                          

                //write the content into the dom
                j$('#categoryTree').html(html);              

                //apply the treeview plugin
                j$("#categoryTree").treeview({
                    persist: "location",
                    collapsed: true,
                    unique: true
                });  

                //if the string that was passed in for callback is actually representative of a function, then call it
                //and pass it the categoryTree html.
                if(typeof({!callback}) == "function")
                {
                    {!callback}(j$("#categoryTree"));                                               
                }
            });    
        });

        //function that is meant to be called recursivly to build tree structure html
        categorySelect.buildTreeHtml = function(category)
        {
            var html = '';     

            //iterate over the category data  
            j$.each(category,function(index,value)
            {
                //create list item for this item.
                html+='<li><a href="#" category="'+value.name+'" class="dataCategoryLink" title="Attach '+value.label+' SLA to Case">'+value.label+'</a>';

                //check to see if this item has any topCategories to iterate over. If so, pass them into this function again after creatining a container               
                if(value.hasOwnProperty('topCategories') && value.topCategories.length > 0)
                {
                    html += '<ul>';
                    html += categorySelect.buildTreeHtml(value.topCategories);                    
                    html +='</ul>';                 
                }   
                //check to see if this item has any childCategories to iterate over. If so, pass them into this function again after creatining a container                           
                else if(value.hasOwnProperty('childCategories')  && value.childCategories.length > 0)
                {
                    html+='<ul>';                   
                    html += categorySelect.buildTreeHtml(value.childCategories);
                    html+='</ul>';
                }
                html += '</li>';
            });
            return html;                
        }

        //fixes the double encoded JSON by replacing html entities with their actual symbol equivilents
        //ex: &quote; becomes "
        categorySelect.htmlDecode = function(value) 
        {
            if (value) 
            {
                return j$('<div />').html(value).text();
            } 
            else
            {
                return '';
            }
        }            
    </script>
    <div id="categoryTreeContainer">
        <ul id="categoryTree">

        </ul>
    </div>
</apex:component>
```

---

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" standardController="Case" showHeader="false" extensions="CaseSlaController">
    <c:categorySelect callback="knowledgePicker.bindTreeClicks" sObjectType="KnowledgeArticleVersion"/>

    <script>           
        var knowledgePicker = new Object();

        knowledgePicker.bindTreeClicks = function(tree)
        {
            j$('.dataCategoryLink').click(function(event,ui){
                event.preventDefault();
                alert('clicked ' + j$(this).attr('category'));
            }); 
        }                           
    </script>   
</apex:page>
```